# Trainings about mobile app testing

Tags: mobile, training

I'm not familiar with trainings about testing because I learned everything my own, but there are - I have - options to attend on different trainings, especially about mobile app testing. Do you know trainings (in English) which worth it about mobile app testing in Europe?

Comment: Why? Do you have any need for training ? since it looks like you have the basics, and that you know how to learn yourself, why don't you try out things and search for training in a more specific area than "mobile testing"?

Answer (score 2):

The iSQI GmbH provide trainings for Mobile App Testing. The most of them in Germany. For more information click on the following link. - https://www.isqi.org/en/mobile-app-testing.html

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to read a book, "Tap into mobile application testing" (https://leanpub.com/testmobileapps) by Jonathan Kohl,  that I think could help you step into mobile application testing area.

In the book, Jonathan tells you about the differences between mobile application testings and traditional ones. And he also tells you about the major technologies used on mobile phone and the best practices in testing them.

Answer (score 0):

You can find some mobile testing workshops nearby using [**MeetUp**](http://www.meetup.com).

> Please also tell are you interested in manual testing or automation?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late answer. I'm interested in both, manual and automated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in mobile automation testing, you can check some courses on udemy, e.g. courses which covers Appium tool: [link](https://www.udemy.com/mobile-automation-using-appiumselenium-3/), [link2](https://www.udemy.com/appium-selendroid-tutorials).
Appium is one of the most used tools for mobile atuomation testing: both native and web

Answer (score 0):

If you're seeking mobile app testing training opportunities in Europe:

Consider ISTQB certification for mobile app testing.
Look into events like the EuroSTAR Conference for workshops and tutorials.
Explore online platforms like Udemy, Coursera, and LinkedIn Learning.
Check for local training providers and bootcamps in your region.
Attend local meetups and workshops for networking and learning opportunities.
Ensure the training covers relevant topics, including automation and security testing, and consider reviews or recommendations from professionals.